# Change MySQL auto_increment value without affecting existing rows

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Is this possible?  Everything I find suggests that it will affect all existing rows if I use alter table and if that happened in my case it would do a lot of damage.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the `auto_increment` value with `ALTER` to a number that is less than the maximum auto incremented value.  MySQL won't let you.  If you want to change the value to *higher* than 1 + the max auto increment value you can do that, but there will be a gap.

Comment: Ok, I understand that and I don't mind the gap.  So if I do something like: alter table mytable autoincrement=30000; and my current high value is 200 it will not change the current rows to the 30000 scheme? They will stay the same?

Comment: @Arringar1   Yes,they will stay the same.

Comment: @Arringar1 they will stay the same, but the next insert will have 30001